# How can I search in month and year in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write a query for searching for month and year only. What I made is searching for month. Can someone tell how I can modify this query to search for month and year like : 5/2019 or 5-2019 ?

```
select firstname, lastname, date  
from tblInfo 
where data = 02/2019
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`MONTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql) and [`YEAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/year-transact-sql) functions from T-SQL:

```sql
SELECT firstname, lastname , date FROM tblInfo 
   WHERE MONTH(date) = 2 AND YEAR(date) = 2019
```

Answer (score 1):

Search for the interval between the first day of the month including and the first day of the following month excluding.

```
SELECT firstname,
       lastname,
       date  
       FROM tblInfo 
       WHERE data >= '2019-02-01'
             AND data < '2019-03-01';
```

This has the advantage over solutions with `datepart()` or `year()` and `month()` that it can use an index on `data` if one is there and therefore perform (way) better in that case.

Using a left open interval instead of a closed one (using `BETWEEN` with the first and last day of the month) also has the advantage that it will also work if `data` has a time portion. If such a date/time is after the last day of the month at 00:00 but before the first day of the next month (at 00:00), for an arbitrary precision of the time fractions, it will be included.

Answer (score 0):

Compare `DATEPART` of date with your constant/variable like:

```
... WHERE DATEPART(yy,tbleInfoAwareness.date) = 2019 AND DATEPART(mm,tbleInfoAwareness.date) = 5
```

Another method is to compare date range - it is better because may use index:

```
.... WHERE tbleInfoAwareness.date BETWEEN '2019-05-01` AND '2019-05-31 23:59:59'
```

PS: Added time for last day.

Comment: Note that `BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31'` will not include records during the end date because `'2019-05-31'` is `'2019-05-31 00:00:00'`

Comment: @DourHighArch I agree. For correct result must be '2019-05-31 23:59:59'. The idea is that when using `tbleInfoAwareness.date` column without other functions like `DATEPART` the server can use index on `date` and scan the records much faster than first method with `DATEPART`.